# Inserting Range into Array in VBA for iteration

Tags: vba, excel

I am facing some issues with VBA. Let me explain what I am trying to achieve. I have 2 sheets in 1 workbook. They are labelled "Sheet1" and "Sheet2."

In "Sheet1," there are 100 rows and 100 columns. In column A, it is filled with eg: SUBJ001 all the way to SUBJ100. In "Sheet2," there is only 1 Column A, with  a range of rows. Eg: "SUBJ003, SUBJ033, SUBJ45." What I am trying to achieve is to use my mouse, highlight the column A in "Sheet2," and compare each individual cell with the cells in column A. Should there be a match, it will copy the entire row and paste them in a new sheet that the macro creates in the same workbook. However, i am experiencing an out of range error at Set Rng =.Find(What:=Arr(I), ... Thanks!

```
Sub Copy_To_Another_Sheet_1()
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim NewSh As Worksheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set Rng = Application.InputBox("Select target range with the mouse", Type:=8)

MyArr = Rng

Set NewSh = Worksheets.Add

With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")

    Rcount = 0

    For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            Do
                Rcount = Rcount + 1

                Rng.EntireRow.Copy NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount)

                ' Use this if you only want to copy the value
                ' NewSh.Range("A" & Rcount).Value = Rng.Value

                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next I
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
```

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyArr = Rng` is setting `MyArr` to be a two-dimensional array where the first rank corresponds to the rows in `Rng` and the second rank corresponds to the columns in `Rng`.

Assuming you only have one column in `Rng`, then your `Find` statement should refer to the values in that first column using `MyArr(I, 1)`, i.e.

```
    Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I, 1), _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
```

Comment: why do you need to `highlight the column A in "Sheet2,"`  ?

Comment: question for the OP

Comment: @jsotola I think I used a wrong choice of word. It should be "select." The reason for that is the cells I am selecting contains the strings I want to do the cross check with